# how to show count based on rank of same user by using sql query?

Tags: jquery, mysql

I need a query to show the count based on rankings of the user

I have a table Polling

```
id    candidate_id    ranking
1      120             1
2      121             2
3      123             3
4      124             4
5      125             5
6      126             6
7      127             7
8      128             8
9      129             9
10     130             10
11     121             3
12     123             5
13     121             1 
14     126             6
15     127             8
16     128             4
17     121             3
18     126             4
```

From this table i need the output as

```
candidate_id     ranking    count
120              1          2
121              1          1
121              2          1
121              3          2
123              3          0
123              4          0
```

Is there anyone can anyone help me in this for writing sql query using mysql?

Comment: What it has to do with `jQuery`?

Comment: he probably thought jquery was a type of sql query

Comment: Please explain the logic you are using to produce the output.

Comment: btw your test data and result don't match (they don't make any sense)

Answer (score -1):

Use group by:

```
SELECT candidate_id,ranking,count(id)
from mytable
group by candidate_id,ranking
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bab8c/1)

Comment: According to the data he provided, this is obviously not the correct answer.

Comment: I think he just gave insufficient data or incorrect data because the question is:"I need a query to show the count based on rankings of the user" which is exactly what my answer is

Comment: Check his data for user 121 in result and data for user 121 in my result, same data there, look at his example data and explain to me how he could possibly get result count 2 for user 120

Comment: I think he gave insufficient data or incorrect data as well, but is it the right thing to do to make up data?

Comment: when did I make up data? I copied the data he is using and I wrote the query in his question, the only thing that is different is the end result (which might I add is correct for user 121) so I assumed this is what the OP needed, if it isn't what he needs he is free to comment and I will alter my query to provide the result he asks for

Comment: "Assumption is the mother of all..."